# Testing expected exceptions with @Commit annotated methods

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-aop, spring-transactions

In my integration tests I want to verify that unique constraint is applied on a certain column. I need to add `@Commit` annotation to force the transaction not to rollback after test is finished.

```
@Commit
@Test(expected = Throwable.class)
public void assertUniqueConstraintsApplied() {
    service.create(ItemBuilder.create()
        .name("Item")
        .quantity(2)
        .build());
    service.create(ItemBuilder.create()
        .name("Item")
        .quantity(2)
        .build());
}
```

The test is failing because the method `assertUniqueConstraintsApplied` by itself is not throwing the exception. The AOP proxy wrapper is the one who is responsible for committing the transaction after the method is finished and JUnit is not aware about it. Just writing `entityManager.flush()` in method seems a little hacky fix, that's why I wonder if there is a way of writing tests which carry this effect.

Comment: So you are testing for an expected exception that is not thrown, as it seems. And now you wonder why it fails. Sorry if I do not understand the question, but you have answered it yourself already, as it seems. BTW, the code explaining your problem is not in your question. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The `@Commit` annotation as described in the doc is used to commit the transaction after the test method. In essence I expect the procedure to fail with constraint violation, thus causing the test to pass. However failure is thrown outside the test method and not captured by JUnit. My question is about finding a pattern to test these kind of scenarios, if it exists.

Comment: Yes, you have a question, fair enough. No problem with that. But I repeat: If you like to get a good answer, it would be quite helpful to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Reproducible problems have a much higher chance of yielding useful answers. If the latter is not so important for you, good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot provide any other code that I think relates to the issue. Thank you though

Comment: False statement! You **can** (because you obviously have the code), but you **choose not to**, probably because you think it is too much work to carve it down to a small [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which does not contain any copyrighted or proprietary stuff anymore, but still reproduces the issue. So you expect others to do that work for you. As I said, good luck! And goodbye.